# PIC Assembly - BCF STATUS,RP0 syntax error

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, pic, xc8

Compiling the following program

```
LADR_0x0010:
    MOVLW 0x10           ;   b'00010000'  d'016'
    BCF STATUS,RP0       ; !!Bank Register-Bank(0/1)-Select
    BCF STATUS,RP1       ; !!Bank Register-Bank(2/3)-Select
    MOVWF LRAM_0x7D
```

gives me syntax error on BCF lines

Comment: Try `BCF STATUS, 5`or just `BCF RP0`

Comment: Have you include `xc.inc`?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Which microcontroller?  Did you add proper MPASM PIC16Fxxx processor include file it to your project?

Comment: @Mike Replacing `RP0` with `5` removes the error. How can I replace RP1?

Comment: Try to answer my questions first, if you wont to know where are you!

Comment: `BCF STATUS, 6`or just `BCF RP1`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build this using MPLABX v5.40 or v5.45 with the pic-as(v2.xx) tool chain this syntax works:

```
LADR_0x0010:
    MOVLW 0x10           ;   b'00010000'  d'016'
    BCF STATUS,STATUS_RP0_POSITION       ; !!Bank Register-Bank(0/1)-Select
    BCF STATUS,STATUS_RP1_POSITION       ; !!Bank Register-Bank(2/3)-Select
    MOVWF LRAM_0x7D
```

Comment: Where is declaration of `STATUS_RP0_POSITION` and `STATUS_RP1_POSITION` ?

Comment: @GJ. It's in the device specific include file for the selected controller that the xc.inc file brings in.

Comment: So you must find that specific file to see how are declared constants to be able to use it! You can find that file manually in MPLABX directory and include it to the project file. The file name looks like:  "P16F18344.INC"

Comment: Just `#include <xc.inc>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using PIC12Fxxx or PIC16Fxxx microcontrollers.
You can read MLAB help file in main menu press `Help`/`Help Contens` and type `banksel`

The help will show:

Application Example 2 -  **banksel**

```
  #include p16f877a.inc   ;Include standard header file
                          ;for the selected device.
 
  banksel TRISB           ;Since this register is in bank 1,
                          ;not default bank 0, banksel is 
                          ;used to ensure bank bits are correct.
  clrf    TRISB           ;Clear TRISB. Sets PORTB to outputs.
  banksel PORTB           ;banksel used to return to bank 0,
                          ;where PORTB is located.
  movlw   0x55            ;Set PORTB value.
  movwf   PORTB
  goto    $
  end                     ;All programs must have an end.
```